# Custom UI with pGina for Credential Provider

Tags: c#, opencv, opencv3.0, gina

I need to know if is there any documentation on how I could add a custom user interface with a code written by me in C# to a credential provider done with pGina (http://pgina.org/) for Windows 10.

I have an application to make facial recognition done with Egmu CV in C# and in another side, I have developed a plugin with pGina to be used as a Windows Credential Provider, but I don't know how to join both things.

The problem I have is that all the documentation I have found on the web, is based on using the Windows user and password inputs interface, but I need to be able to show the webcam capture in the logon and unlock screens, authenticate the user using the app I've done, and if everything is right, authorize the user to access the computer. The KeyLemon app, has this feature, I need to know if it is possible to do it with pGina, to avoid the pain of creating all the CP code from scratch.

Any help will be really appreciated.
Thank you very much!!!!!!

Comment: Hi @Damian did you ever found any solution to this.. I am facing something similar

Comment: Unfortunately, I abandoned the project, and created a solution for web applications using Node Js and Open CV. It's been hard to find the way to do it so I decided to move forward in a different way. Hope you can find some help!